# MethodNotAllowedHttpException in RouteCollection

Tags: laravel

I have the  `MethodNotAllowedHttpException` error when I try to update a data

I try to change the `Form::model` route to `PUT` and `PATCH`

Here's my form::model:

```php
{!! Form::model($mission, ['route' => ['missions.update', $mission->id_missions], 'method' => 'PUT', 'class' => 'form-horizontal panel']) !!}
```

And here's my route:

```php
Route::resource('missions', 'MissionsController');
```

I got the error mentionned above

Can somebody help me please ?

Comment: More detail is definitely needed. You may need to add a full stacktrace, awa `php artisan route:list`

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you forgot to spoof the `PUT` method in your form, you can do that by using blade's `@method('PUT')`.

This is how you can implement it :

```
<form action="/foo/bar" method="POST">
    @method('PUT')
</form>
```

So try also changing the form's method to `POST` when you use the `Form::model` helper because HTML forms can only be sent by `GET` or `POST` methods hence why one has to spoof the other CRUD methods.

You can read more about that [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/controllers#resource-controllers).

Comment: I tried your solution, the problem is that instead of updating the mission, it replicates it with the new parameters

Comment: Did you also try `@method('PATCH')`?

Comment: Yes, same result

Comment: and in the form method, did you change it to `'method' => 'POST'`?

Comment: yup, my form looks like this:

`{!! Form::model($mission, ['route' => ['missions.update', $mission->id_missions], 'method' => 'POST', 'class' => 'form-horizontal panel']) !!}
   @method('PATCH')`

Comment: Then probably the issue is on your controller side in the `update` method, you might be adding those data in that method instead of updating them.

Comment: What do you mean by that ? Maybe you would like to see the update method ?

Comment: You mean in the Form::open ?

Comment: Yeah, you should test to see if you receive `id_missions` on your `update` method in your controller, but as you said it is replicating them with new parameters I guess it is not a problem so the problem comes from your update method which replicates data instead of updating it.

Comment: It didn't work. I'm gonna remake a controller, a repository and forms. Thanks for help

Comment: I don't think you need to start over again, from what you said in the first post, it looks like the `update` method from your controller does replicate the data you are passing instead of updating it so I don't know if you use SQL or another DB system but it might probably come from the way you deal with the query on that DB, your query is probably just replaciting data instead of updating it.

Comment: If after you checked it still doesn't work, then you can start over again but I don't think it's going to fix the issue unless you do it in an other way, if you still face that issue you can still post a new question on stackoverflow.